# Update Collection by using Data from that Collection in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, updates

I Have a collection which has data like `{m:1,n:3}`

want to update this collection like `{m:1,n:3,s:4}`

where `s= m+n` in mongodb,

so for that, I tried

```
db.data.update({},{$set:{s:(m+n)});
```

but it doesn't work and I tried multiple things but still haven't a solution. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with aggregation you can `$addFields` and `$out` to a collection

```
db.col.aggregate([
    {$addFields : {s : {$add:["$m", "$n"]}}},
    {$out : "col"}
])
```

with `$project` for mongo version less than 3.4

```
db.col.aggregate([
    {$project : {m:1, n:1, s : {$add:["$m", "$n"]}}},
    {$out : "col"}
])
```

result

```
> db.col.drop()
true

> db.col.insert({m:2,n:4})
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })

> db.col.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a911efc6bb20635697c6b17"), "m" : 2, "n" : 4 }

> db.col.aggregate([{$addFields : {s : {$add:["$m", "$n"]}}},{$out : "col"}])

> db.col.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a911efc6bb20635697c6b17"), "m" : 2, "n" : 4, "s" : 6 }
>
```

Comment: when i execute db.col.aggregate([{$addFields : {s : {$add:["$m", "$n"]}}},{$out : "col"}]) it throgh error
  Mongo Server error (MongoCommandException): Command failed with error 16436: 'Unrecognized pipeline stage name: '$addFields'' on server localhost:27017.

Comment: updated with `$project` for mongo version less than 3.4

Comment: So for less than 3.4, I have to mention all key of that collection in $project? @Saravana

Comment: Yes will have to, by default it includes _id we can exclude it by setting 0 @manoj

Comment: In real environment this will be painfull :D